# Is there a way to change Sender Name Using Workflow or Process Builder?

Tags: apex, workflow, singleemailmessage

I want to change display name of "Email from Name", I know we have `setsenderdisplayName` property available in `SingleMailMessage`  but I don't want to go with Apex, please advise if any out of box option available to achieve this.

Comment: Not that I can think of, on the email alert that it calls you can set it to default workflow owner or current user's email address, but I don't see any other setting options on it.

Comment: @DaveHumm I am aware of that but I am looking for option where in I can take input from User and set SenderdisplayName accordingly using workflow or any out of box  feature.